# Single search box Web2py, union usage

Tags: union, web2py, data-access-layer

I am trying to create a single search box on my website.
First I split up the search input in multiple strings using `split()`.
Then I am looping over the multiple strings I created with `split()`,  with every string I create a query. These query's will be stored in a list.

In the next step I am trying to execute all those query's and store the results (rows) in another list.

The next thing I want to do is union all these results(rows). In this case the final result will be an output of a query containing all the different keywords used in the searchbox.

This is my code:

```
def ajaxlivesearch():
    str = request.vars.values()[0]
    a=str.split()
    items = []
    q = []
    r =[]
    for partialstr in a:
        q.append((db.profiel.sport.like('%'+partialstr+'%'))|(db.profiel.speelsterkte.like('%'+partialstr+'%'))|(db.profiel.plaats.like('%'+partialstr+'%')))

   for query in q:
       r.append(db(query).select(groupby=db.profiel.id))

   for results in r:
       for (i,row) in enumerate(results):
           items.append(DIV(A(B(row.id_user.first_name) ,NBSP(1), B(row.id_user.last_name),BR(), I(row.sport),I(','), NBSP(1), I(row.speelsterkte),I(','), NBSP(1),I(row.plaats),HR(), _id="res%s"%i, _href=row.id_user, _onclick="copyToBox($('#res%s').html())"%i), _id="resultLiveSearch"))

    return TAG[''](*items)
```

My question is: How do I union the multiple results(rows)?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the [union of two `Rows` objects](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06/the-database-abstraction-layer#Combining-rows) (removing duplicates) as follows:

```
rows_union = rows1 | rows2
```

However, it would be more efficient to get all the records in a single query. To simplify, you can also use the `.contains` method rather than using `.like` and wrapping each term with `%`s.

```
fields = ['sport', 'speelsterkte', 'plaats']
query_terms = [db.profiel[f].contains(term) for f in fields for term in a]
query = reduce(lambda a, b: a | b, query_terms)
results = db(query).select()
```

Also, you are not using any aggregation functions, so it is not clear why you have specified the `groupby` argument (and in any case, each record has a unique `id`, so grouping would have no effect). Perhaps you instead meant `orderby=db.profiel.id`.

Finally, it is probably not a good idea to do `request.vars.values()[0]`, as `request.vars` is a dictionary-like object, and the particular value of interest is not guaranteed to be the first item in `.values()`. Instead, just refer to the name of the particular variable (e.g., `request.vars.keyword`), which is also more efficient because you are extracting a single item rather than converting all values to a list.